# dart timer goes wrong?

Tags: dart, dart-async

It's my first program in Dart, and I just wanted to see it's asynchronous capabilities. Knowing javascript I wrote the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:async' show Timer;
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  //Recursion
  fib1(x) => x > 1 ? fib1(x-1) + fib1(x-2) : x;
  //Mathematical
  num fi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
  fib2(x) => x > 1 ? ((pow(fi, x) + pow(1 - fi, x)) / sqrt(5)).round() : x;
  //Linear
  fib3(x) {
    if(x < 2) return x;
    int a1  = 0;
    int a2  = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
      sum = a2 + a1;
      a1 = a2;
      a2 = sum;
    }

    return sum;
  }

  Timer.run(() => print('Fib1:' + fib1(41).toString()));
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib2:' + fib2(41).toString()));
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib3:' + fib3(41).toString()));
}
```

and the output on the dart editor is:

```
Fib1:165580141
Fib2:165580141
Fib3:165580141
```

All 3 outputs are printed at the same time. Isn't that wrong? fib3 is much faster and should be printed first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running asynchronous doesn't mean multithreaded. Dart runs singlethreaded. You can spawn isolates to run code in parallel.

When you add a print statement

```dart
{
  //...
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib1:' + fib1(41).toString()));
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib2:' + fib2(41).toString()));
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib3:' + fib3(41).toString()));
  print('exit');
}
```

after your three `Timer.run(...` statements you get a glimpse what async is about.

The closure you provide with `Timer.run(...)` gets scheduled for later execution and the next statement of your main is executed.
As soon as the event loop has time to process scheduled tasks your closures are executed one by one.

You can find more in-depth information here: [The Event Loop and Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/)

** EDIT **

When you run it this way the output may make more sense for you

```dart
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib1: ${new DateTime.now()} - result: ${fib1(41)}'));
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib2: ${new DateTime.now()} - result: ${fib2(41)}'));
  Timer.run(() => print('Fib3: ${new DateTime.now()} - result: ${fib3(41)}'));
  print('exit');
```

** output **

```
exit
Fib1: 2014-01-07 12:00:46.953 - result: 165580141
Fib2: 2014-01-07 12:00:56.208 - result: 165580141
Fib3: 2014-01-07 12:00:56.210 - result: 165580141
```

It's not the case that the faster task ends first. `Timer.run()` schedules for later execution and the execution of `main()` continues. When the event loop get's back the control of the program flow it executes the scheduled tasks one at a time and one after the other.

Maybe the output is buffered somehow by DartEditor output window or shell and shown in batches. 
This may lead to the impression that the results are printed all at once.

** EDIT 2 **

I just saw that the results are written one by one.
It's easy to verify if you move the slow `Fib1` at the last position (after `Fib3`)

Comment: I don't assume asynchronous is necessarily multithreaded, I program in NodeJS which has singlethreaded async i/o too. And I know the faster program ends first. Fib3 is tons faster than fib2 and fib1 and it still waits for them to finish and then all prints are executed synchronously one by one, which is strange.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question.

Comment: yes I thought some kind of sequencial execution with buffered output, but it is very strange for what they tell you on the documentation. I thought `Timer.run` is equivalent to javascript's `setTimeout(callback,0)`

Comment: Why do you think `setTimeout(callback,0) is different? AFAIK it isn't

Comment: write the equivalent code in javascript and execute it (not dart2js, I ran the generated javascript code with nodejs and it did the same with DartEditor). You will see different results like I did using chrome console

Comment: I'm not used to JS and don't have NodeJS on my system so it's too much expenditure. Maybe someone else can provide additional information. I have no explanation why this could behave differently in JS. What I read about NodeJS showed hat it works very similar to Dart with respect to ansynchronous execution.

Comment: yes you are right. I thought asynchronous calls were pseudoparallel executed in single thread